# How to insert multiple leads at once through webforms in vtiger crm?

Tags: crm, vtiger

I have a webform which enters leads into **vtiger crm** . The webform is as follows:

```
<form name="Test" action="http://localhost:8888/modules/Webforms/capture.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="publicid"      value="9227539ebf714c64888c6f8a26b4c1f9"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Test"></input>
</p>

<p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="firstname"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="lastname"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="company"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Country</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="country"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ></input>
</p>
```

This form works absolutely fine with the lead getting inserted into my CRM.
But, now I want to add/insert multiple leads using a webform like this:

```
<form name="Test" action="http://localhost:8888/modules/Webforms/capture.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="publicid" value="9227539ebf714c64888c6f8a26b4c1f9"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Test"></input>
</p>

<p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="firstname[]"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="lastname[]"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="company[]"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Country</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="country[]"  required="true"></input>
</p>


<p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="firstname[]"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="lastname[]"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="company[]"  required="true"></input>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Country</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="country[]"  required="true"></input>
</p>



<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ></input>
</p>
```

In this form, I am trying to add two lead records into the CRM. But this doesn't work. Rather it enters only one record into the CRM like this abc |##| pqr , where 'abc' and 'pqr' are the firstname field entries respectively.

I am completely new to vTiger crm. Please help me out and suggest me some good developer guidebooks. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is your vtiger/webform version?

Answer (score 0):

You can only insert a lead at a time. The PHP code in capture.php isn't prepare to iterate over array form fields. You must do multiple requests to enter as many leads as you need to.